# ExpressionEngine on MediaTemple - removing index.php results in "no input file specified"

Tags: expressionengine, mediatemple

I have an MT site with the standard ExpressionEngine htaccess code to remove index.php and the home page works, and all other pages work if I put index.php in the URL. Without it, I get "no output file specified". It works on my local and non-MT server, so I know its an environment thing. What in the htaccess needs to be changed to make it work on MT?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Use Dynamic robots.txt file
# ------------------------------
RewriteRule robots\.txt /robots.php [L]


# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/admin/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]


# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you use this approach of adding a ? at the end of index.php AND you use 301 redirects to redirect old pages to new pages, you may find your redirect goes to a 404 page with the URL /?/old-page. In this case dont use 301 redirect, but use a RewriteRule. See here:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/167241/#799494

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted a Gist last night with my standard rewrite rules for all my ExpressionEngine sites on (mt).

```
## BEGIN Expression Engine Rewrite

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

## END Expression Engine Rewrite
```

Comment: I am using MediaTemple DV4 and my standard .htaccess wouldn't work after I upgraded. This answer is what solved the problem for me.

Comment: I just found this out last week, Plesk by default sets up servers running PHP as FastCGI, hence the `?` needed in the last rewrite rule. I was totally unaware of this until the other day. Switching back to run PHP under Apache allows the removal of the `?`. See this thread for more context on 301 issues I was having: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/301-redirects-appending-query-string/5218#5218

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @danielcgold for the answer via twitter:

Try using this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` and note the ? after index.php

Comment: Woud be great if Chad could edit the original post with the working script. It's a little unclear as to what the correct iteration is, and  I would definitely like to try this .htaccess file.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell replace the very last line with Chad's correction.

Answer (score 1):

Using EE 2.7.0 and Mediatemple's Grid service (formerly "GS"), I've had luck using the standard .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but then going into the AccountCenter > [mydomain.com] > PHP Settings, and changing the PHP version from **5.5.1 CGI (latest)** to **5.3.7 CGI (stable)**.

Answer (score 1):

I posted [this solution](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/32164/2432) on the ExpressionEngine Stack Exchange site, but in a nutshell the shared hosting environment we had to use was forced to use FastCGI, and we couldn't modify any CGI or PHP configurations.

In an attempt to create the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable myself, what worked for me was this 3 step 'custom' approach:

1. First, in `ExpressionEngine > CP Home > Admin > System Administration > Output And Debugging`, I set **Force URL query strings** to **No**.
2. Next, as mentioned in previous answers, I changed the `.htaccess` directive from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` **to** `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` (extra ? after index.php).
3. Finally, I added this piece of custom PHP code to the top of site root's `index.php` file to "force" the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable into accurate existence:

   ```
   <?php

       $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
       $pos = strpos($path, '?');
       if ($pos !== false)
           $path = substr($path, 0, $pos);
       $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $path;

       /**
        * ExpressionEngine - by EllisLab
          ...
          ...
   ```

I hope this helps someone! I really pulled my hair out trying to find somewhat more elegant solutions!